# Como executar um javascript referenciando um ID de um botão?

Tags: javascript, css

Eu preciso executar um javascript, mais eu gostaria de fazer isso usando o ID do botão que fez o click,

Exemplo:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
  $("p").click(function(){
      alert("estou usando o P.");
  });

  $('teste').on('click',function(){
        //eu precisa de alguma coisa assim
         alert("estou usando o id."); 
  });
```

});

Como usar referenciar o id?.

Neste exemplo só funciona quando usar a tag "P"

Agradeço

Comment: reformula a pergunta que ficou confusa.

Comment: vou fazer isso agora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var btn1 = document.querySelector("#mostrarcampo");
btn1.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    document.querySelector("#extratres").style.display = 'block';
 });
```

isto faz o mesmo que o trecho

```
$('#mostracampo1').on('click',function(){
    //eu precisava de alguma coisa assim
    document.getElementById("extratres").style.display = 'block';
```

});

Comment: o trecho que você mostra não funciona, eu já testei

Comment: eu mudei a minha pergunta para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: Você esta certo, eu fiz o teste e deu certo